# transforming stacked data into horizontal data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

this query:

```
; with numbered as
(
  select *,
      -- Assign number to each record
      -- Numbering is separate for each pair of MLISNPI and CLIENT_ID1
      -- Highest [Sum of desc] will get number 1 and so forth
         Rank() over (partition by [MLISNPI]
                            order by [Sum of count] desc) rn
    from [TargettingReport]
),
ctemain as (
select [MLISNPI],
       [CLIENT_ID1], 
       [Sum of count]
  from numbered
)


select * from ctemain
```

is returning this example data:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
| MLISNPI  | CLIENT_ID1 | Sum of count |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 03001363 |     101522 |          436 |
| 03001363 |     101596 |            0 |
| 03001363 |     101597 |            0 |
| 03002312 |     102165 |           66 |
| 03002742 |     100062 |            1 |
| 03002742 |     211074 |         1229 |
| 03006958 |     102235 |           21 |
| 03014986 |     213926 |            5 |
| 03016270 |     213143 |            3 |
| 03023284 |     212876 |           44 |
| 03023284 |     213801 |           55 |
| 03023821 |     100218 |            0 |
| 03028812 |     211144 |          133 |
| 03041666 |     100236 |          346 |
| 03041666 |     103164 |           65 |
| 03051731 |     213402 |          157 |
| 03058777 |     100572 |           28 |
| 03065509 |     101632 |           29 |
| 03071952 |     213632 |            6 |
| 03072059 |     101506 |            4 |
| 03081449 |     100087 |          398 |
| 03083205 |     214311 |            7 |
| 03117698 |     210178 |          203 |
| 03121302 |     214008 |            9 |
| 03139502 |     102179 |         1635 |
| 03147455 |     216022 |           21 |
| 03149204 |     211425 |            1 |
| 03186883 |     215748 |            1 |
| 03186883 |     215749 |           10 |
| 03190331 |     212289 |           26 |
| 03800285 |     101108 |         8052 |
| 03800285 |     101596 |            0 |
| 03800285 |     101597 |            0 |
| 03800350 |     212419 |            9 |
| 03800616 |     110461 |            0 |
| 03800616 |     213456 |            3 |
| 03802018 |     103136 |           32 |
| 03803412 |     201257 |            3 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

but i actually need the data horizontally like this PER `MLISNPI`:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| MLISNPI  | clientid1 | sumofcount1 | clientid 2 | sumofcount2 | client id 3 | sum of 3 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 03001363 |    101522 |         436 |     101596 |           0 |      101597 |        0 |
| 03002312 |    102165 |          66 |            |             |             |          |
| 03002742 |    100062 |           1 |     211074 |        1229 |             |          |
| 03006958 |    102235 |          21 |            |             |             |          |
| 03014986 |    213926 |           5 |            |             |             |          |
| 03016270 |    213143 |           3 |            |             |             |          |
| 03023284 |    212876 |          44 |     213801 |          55 |             |          |
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

how can i get the data in this format?

here's the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargettingReport](
    [MLISNPI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IMS_PRESCRIBER_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CLIENT_ID1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Sum of count] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: It's not clear how a `clientid` ends up in `clientid1`, `clientid 2` or `client id 3` based on what you've given us. Can you describe how those columns should be generated, as though you were doing it manually?

Comment: @NathanielFord thank you. client2 would be the same MLISNPI but its (sumofcount) would be second greatest for that specific MLISNPI, whereas client3 it would have sumofcount 3rd greatest for that specific MLISNPI

Comment: [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is where you should start.  A workable CREATE TABLE def for TargettingReport, with sample inserts, would help. You could put it up on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: @RossPresser i've added a create table thanks so much rfo ryour help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to perform this with a `PIVOT`.  If you know the number of columns you will have then you can use a static version.

This does both an `UNPIVOT` and then a `PIVOT` to assign a `row_number()` to each column to then transform:

```
select *
from
(
  select MLISNPI,
    cast(value as int) value,
    case col 
      when 'client_id1' then 'clientid_' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
      when 'SumofCount' then 'SumofCount_' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
    end col
  from
  (
    select MLISNPI, Client_id1, cast(SumOfCount as varchar(50)) SumofCount,
      row_number() over(partition by MLISNPI order by Client_id1) rn
    from TargettingReport
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (client_id1, sumofcount)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in ([clientid_1], [SumofCount_1], 
              [clientid_2], [SumofCount_2],
              [clientid_3], [SumofCount_3])
) p
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58077/13)

If you are going to have a unknown number of `row_number()`s that will be applied to the columns, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot 
  = stuff((select ','
           +quotename(C.name )
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('TargettingReport') and
               C.name IN ('CLIENT_ID1', 'SumOfCount')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @colsPivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(case when C.name = 'client_id1' then 'clientid' else c.name end + '_' + cast(rn as varchar(10)))
         from sys.columns as C
         cross apply
         ( 
           select row_number() over(partition by MLISNPI order by Client_id1) rn
            from TargettingReport
          ) x
         where C.object_id = object_id('TargettingReport') and
               C.name IN ('CLIENT_ID1', 'SumOfCount')
         group by name, rn
         order by rn
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = ' 
      select *
      from
      (
        select MLISNPI,
          cast(value as int) value, 
           case col 
            when ''client_id1'' then ''clientid_'' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
            when ''SumofCount'' then ''SumofCount_'' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
          end col
        from 
        (
          select MLISNPI, Client_id1, cast(SumOfCount as varchar(50)) SumofCount,
            row_number() over(partition by MLISNPI order by Client_id1) rn
          from TargettingReport
        ) x1
        unpivot 
        (
           value
           for col in (' + @colsUnPivot + ')
        ) unpvt 

      ) x2
      pivot
      (
        sum(value)
        for col in(' + @colsPivot +')
      )p'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58077/56)

Answer (score 1):

Please , you study  about 'Pivot'  and can you do like that :
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(wagecode) 
                  FROM t1 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT empid, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select empid, wagecode, amount
                 from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amount)
                for wagecode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```